# Dictionary with single item

Tags: c#, dictionary

In the case where `Dictionary<object, object>` `myDictionary` happens to contain a single item, what is the best way to retrieve the value object (if I don't care about the key) ?

```
if (myDictionary.Count == 1)
{
    // Doesn't work
    object obj = myDictionary.Values[0];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious about why you would need this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on whether you want it to fail if there's multiple object or not you can use either

```
myDictionary.Values.Single(); // Will fail if there's more than one
```

or

```
myDictionary.Values.First(); // Will just return the first regardless of the count
```

Comment: .FirstOrDefault() is the safest, since it returns null if there are none, and the null can be checked safely.

Comment: @Cylon: However, that can't determine if it's null because the value of the item is null or because there was no item.

Comment: @Gaffa, you can make that distinction, if it's important, by checking the number of keys in the dictionary. On the other hand, I'd consider that creating a key, with a corresponding null value, is a bug.

Comment: @cylon if no objects is an exceptional situation it should be treated as such, not masked as a null reference. returning null if your not testing for it is not safe and if you're going to test for null you might as well let the code show that no objects is an exceptional situation and then handle the potential exception

Comment: @Rune, "null" has a very specific meaning: there might be a value that could go here, but we don't know what it is. This is entirely different from "an exceptional condition" which should simply be thrown as an exception.

Comment: @cylon agreed null has by definition the value of unknown. That however doesn't make it safe (try calling a method)
so it's not a matter of what's "safest" but wether or not the dictionary having a count != 1 is an exceptional situation or not

Comment: DW care to comment on why? This does indeed solve the problem is there something you think is incorrect or needs to be improved?

Answer (score 3):

```
object obj = myDictionary.Values.Single();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would never code for the assumption that there will only be one. If you know there's always going to be exactly one, then why use a dictionary?

Comment: I came looking for what to do in this situation with this thought. Unfortunately, my situation is returning a key and value in a web API. In JSON for instance, Dictionaries associate the key and value together while a KeyValuePair associates the key with "Key" and the value with "Value" instead of to each other, which I find to be less than ideal. Any chance you could expand upon the thoughts you hint at in this answer?

Comment: Adding JSON to the mix does change things; you need to model on server side what the client side expects. So in this case, a dictionary works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value directly or by index, you have to either know the key:

```
object obj = yourDictionary[theKeyThatYouHappenToKnow];
```

or use an enumerator:

```
var en = yourDictionary.GetEnumerator();
en.MoveNext();
object obj = en.Current.Value;
en.Dispose();
```

If you are using framework 3.5, you can also some extension method like `Single` or `First` to use the enumerator for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an iterator.

`myDictionary.GetEnumerator().Current`

Comment: The enumerator starts before the first item, you have to call MoveNext to advance to the first item.